# Best way to create a RadGrid / GridView that will have dynamic grid template columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, telerik

I am in a bit of a situation here with the Telerik RadGrid and making it match my dynamic datasource.

**The grid requirements are the following:**
Col1 - ProductCategoryName is a static DataBoundColumn

Col2 - ProductTier is a static GridTemplateColumn (w/ a ComboBox in the ItemTemplate so the user can select a value that applies to all dynamic columns the row when saving)

All additional columns are generated based on the datasource.
i.e. DynCol3 - Product1, DynCol4 - Product2, DynCol5 Product3. Each of these columns will have an Edit link (ASPHyperlink) in them with an onclick=openDialogWindow function.

As you can tell by the grid structure: The purpose of the grid is for each product tier the user will click an edit link that will open a dialog window. Col2 is just a ComboBox selected value that applies to all Tiers in that row.

**The problem and everything I have tried:**
I figured there are only 2 ways to go about this, primarily because the grid has Dynamic GridTemplateColumns. When this is the case I believe there are only 2 options:

1. Create the grid 100% Programmatically in the Page_Init to match the datatable structure that is bound to it. Using an ITemplate Class for both the ComboBox col and the dynamic GridTemplate cols that have ASPHyperLinks in them. This has caused me all kinds of problems with ViewState and the grid continuously disappearing on every page postback.
2. Create the entire grid as a static grid with about 15 Static GridTemplate columns for the Tiers. All of the Tier columns would be set to visible = false. Then based on the datasource and how many dynamic columns I actually need to use I would make that # of columns visible, and set the appropriate header text on each of them. The problem with this method, is that I have no idea how to hide/show the columns based on the datasource and it just seems like a bad way to do it but I might have to as a last resort.

I am open to any suggestions / help.